# cmake error with codeblocks mingw and glfw in windows 10

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, codeblocks, glfw

Hello I am just starting out in programming and I am trying to setup CodeBlocks with mingw compiler and glfw under Windows 10. When trying to cmake the CMakeList.txt in the glfw folder, I get a "broken" status when it check for working C compiler. I installed the CodeBlocks with mingw included. Any ideas?

```sh
D:\MiscPrograms\CMake\bin>cmake .<br>
-- The C compiler identification is unknown<br>
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/MiscPrograms/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe<br>
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/MiscPrograms/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken<br>
CMake Error at D:/MiscPrograms/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):<br>
  The C compiler

    "D:/MiscPrograms/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/MiscPrograms/CMake/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):D:/MiscPrograms/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_cb62d/fast && D:/MiscPrograms/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_cb62d.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_cb62d.dir/build
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/MiscPrograms/CMake/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_cb62d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    D:\MiscPrograms\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_cb62d.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c D:\MiscPrograms\CMake\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    CMakeFiles\cmTC_cb62d.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_cb62d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_cb62d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/MiscPrograms/CMake/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:120: recipe for target 'cmTC_cb62d/fast' failed
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_cb62d/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.<br>
Call Stack (most recent call first):<br>
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)<br>


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!<br>
See also "D:/MiscPrograms/CMake/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".<br>
See also "D:/MiscPrograms/CMake/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".<br>
```

CMakeList.txt from glfw website download zip package

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(GLFW VERSION 3.3.2 LANGUAGES C)

set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 OFF)

if (POLICY CMP0054)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)
endif()

if (POLICY CMP0077)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0077 NEW)
endif()

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)
option(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build the GLFW example programs" ON)
option(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS "Build the GLFW test programs" ON)
option(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS "Build the GLFW documentation" ON)
option(GLFW_INSTALL "Generate installation target" ON)
option(GLFW_VULKAN_STATIC "Assume the Vulkan loader is linked with the application" OFF)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(CMakeDependentOption)

cmake_dependent_option(GLFW_USE_OSMESA "Use OSMesa for offscreen context creation" OFF
                       "UNIX" OFF)
cmake_dependent_option(GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG "Force use of high-performance GPU on hybrid systems" OFF
                       "WIN32" OFF)
cmake_dependent_option(GLFW_USE_WAYLAND "Use Wayland for window creation" OFF
                       "UNIX;NOT APPLE" OFF)
cmake_dependent_option(USE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL "Use MSVC runtime library DLL" ON
                       "MSVC" OFF)

if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    set(_GLFW_BUILD_DLL 1)
endif()

if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS AND UNIX)
    # On Unix-like systems, shared libraries can use the soname system.
    set(GLFW_LIB_NAME glfw)
else()
    set(GLFW_LIB_NAME glfw3)
endif()

if (GLFW_VULKAN_STATIC)
    if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
        # If you absolutely must do this, remove this line and add the Vulkan
        # loader static library via the CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
        message(FATAL_ERROR "You are trying to link the Vulkan loader static library into the GLFW shared library")
    endif()
    set(_GLFW_VULKAN_STATIC 1)
endif()

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/modules")

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

if (GLFW_BUILD_DOCS)
    set(DOXYGEN_SKIP_DOT TRUE)
    find_package(Doxygen)
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set compiler specific flags
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (MSVC)
    if (MSVC90)
        # Workaround for VS 2008 not shipping with the DirectX 9 SDK
        include(CheckIncludeFile)
        check_include_file(dinput.h DINPUT_H_FOUND)
        if (NOT DINPUT_H_FOUND)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "DirectX 9 headers not found; install DirectX 9 SDK")
        endif()
        # Workaround for VS 2008 not shipping with stdint.h
        list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/vs2008")
    endif()

    if (NOT USE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL)
        foreach (flag CMAKE_C_FLAGS
                      CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
                      CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
                      CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
                      CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO)

            if (${flag} MATCHES "/MD")
                string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${flag} "${${flag}}")
            endif()
            if (${flag} MATCHES "/MDd")
                string(REGEX REPLACE "/MDd" "/MTd" ${flag} "${${flag}}")
            endif()

        endforeach()
    endif()
endif()

if (MINGW)
    # Workaround for legacy MinGW not providing XInput and DirectInput
    include(CheckIncludeFile)

    check_include_file(dinput.h DINPUT_H_FOUND)
    check_include_file(xinput.h XINPUT_H_FOUND)
    if (NOT DINPUT_H_FOUND OR NOT XINPUT_H_FOUND)
        list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/mingw")
    endif()

    # Enable link-time exploit mitigation features enabled by default on MSVC
    include(CheckCCompilerFlag)

    # Compatibility with data execution prevention (DEP)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-Wl,--nxcompat")
    check_c_compiler_flag("" _GLFW_HAS_DEP)
    if (_GLFW_HAS_DEP)
        set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--nxcompat ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endif()

    # Compatibility with address space layout randomization (ASLR)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-Wl,--dynamicbase")
    check_c_compiler_flag("" _GLFW_HAS_ASLR)
    if (_GLFW_HAS_ASLR)
        set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--dynamicbase ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endif()

    # Compatibility with 64-bit address space layout randomization (ASLR)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-Wl,--high-entropy-va")
    check_c_compiler_flag("" _GLFW_HAS_64ASLR)
    if (_GLFW_HAS_64ASLR)
        set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--high-entropy-va ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Detect and select backend APIs
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (GLFW_USE_WAYLAND)
    set(_GLFW_WAYLAND 1)
    message(STATUS "Using Wayland for window creation")
elseif (GLFW_USE_OSMESA)
    set(_GLFW_OSMESA 1)
    message(STATUS "Using OSMesa for headless context creation")
elseif (WIN32)
    set(_GLFW_WIN32 1)
    message(STATUS "Using Win32 for window creation")
elseif (APPLE)
    set(_GLFW_COCOA 1)
    message(STATUS "Using Cocoa for window creation")
elseif (UNIX)
    set(_GLFW_X11 1)
    message(STATUS "Using X11 for window creation")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "No supported platform was detected")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find and add Unix math and time libraries
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    find_library(RT_LIBRARY rt)
    mark_as_advanced(RT_LIBRARY)
    if (RT_LIBRARY)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${RT_LIBRARY}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-lrt")
    endif()

    find_library(MATH_LIBRARY m)
    mark_as_advanced(MATH_LIBRARY)
    if (MATH_LIBRARY)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${MATH_LIBRARY}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-lm")
    endif()

    if (CMAKE_DL_LIBS)
        list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
        list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-l${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
    endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use Win32 for window creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_WIN32)

    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_LIBS "-lgdi32")

    if (GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG)
        set(_GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG 1)
    endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use X11 for window creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_X11)

    find_package(X11 REQUIRED)

    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "x11")

    # Set up library and include paths
    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${X11_X11_LIB}" "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")

    # Check for XRandR (modern resolution switching and gamma control)
    if (NOT X11_Xrandr_INCLUDE_PATH)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "RandR headers not found; install libxrandr development package")
    endif()

    # Check for Xinerama (legacy multi-monitor support)
    if (NOT X11_Xinerama_INCLUDE_PATH)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Xinerama headers not found; install libxinerama development package")
    endif()

    # Check for Xkb (X keyboard extension)
    if (NOT X11_Xkb_INCLUDE_PATH)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "XKB headers not found; install X11 development package")
    endif()

    # Check for Xcursor (cursor creation from RGBA images)
    if (NOT X11_Xcursor_INCLUDE_PATH)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Xcursor headers not found; install libxcursor development package")
    endif()

    # Check for XInput (modern HID input)
    if (NOT X11_Xi_INCLUDE_PATH)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "XInput headers not found; install libxi development package")
    endif()

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${X11_Xrandr_INCLUDE_PATH}"
                                  "${X11_Xinerama_INCLUDE_PATH}"
                                  "${X11_Xkb_INCLUDE_PATH}"
                                  "${X11_Xcursor_INCLUDE_PATH}"
                                  "${X11_Xi_INCLUDE_PATH}")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use Wayland for window creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_WAYLAND)
    find_package(ECM REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${ECM_MODULE_PATH}")

    find_package(Wayland REQUIRED Client Cursor Egl)
    find_package(WaylandScanner REQUIRED)
    find_package(WaylandProtocols 1.15 REQUIRED)

    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "wayland-egl")

    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${Wayland_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${Wayland_LIBRARIES}" "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")

    find_package(XKBCommon REQUIRED)
    list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${XKBCOMMON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

    include(CheckIncludeFiles)
    include(CheckFunctionExists)
    check_include_files(xkbcommon/xkbcommon-compose.h HAVE_XKBCOMMON_COMPOSE_H)
    check_function_exists(memfd_create HAVE_MEMFD_CREATE)

    if (NOT ("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" STREQUAL "Linux"))
        find_package(EpollShim)
        if (EPOLLSHIM_FOUND)
            list(APPEND glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS "${EPOLLSHIM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
            list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${EPOLLSHIM_LIBRARIES}")
        endif()
    endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use OSMesa for offscreen context creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_OSMESA)
    find_package(OSMesa REQUIRED)
    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use Cocoa for window creation and NSOpenGL for context creation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (_GLFW_COCOA)

    list(APPEND glfw_LIBRARIES
        "-framework Cocoa"
        "-framework IOKit"
        "-framework CoreFoundation")

    set(glfw_PKG_DEPS "")
    set(glfw_PKG_LIBS "-framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add the Vulkan loader as a dependency if necessary
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (GLFW_VULKAN_STATIC)
    list(APPEND glfw_PKG_DEPS "vulkan")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Export GLFW library dependencies
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
foreach(arg ${glfw_PKG_DEPS})
    set(GLFW_PKG_DEPS "${GLFW_PKG_DEPS} ${arg}")
endforeach()
foreach(arg ${glfw_PKG_LIBS})
    set(GLFW_PKG_LIBS "${GLFW_PKG_LIBS} ${arg}")
endforeach()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create generated files
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

set(GLFW_CONFIG_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/glfw3")

configure_package_config_file(src/glfw3Config.cmake.in
                              src/glfw3Config.cmake
                              INSTALL_DESTINATION "${GLFW_CONFIG_PATH}"
                              NO_CHECK_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS_MACRO)

write_basic_package_version_file(src/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake
                                 VERSION ${GLFW_VERSION}
                                 COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

configure_file(src/glfw_config.h.in src/glfw_config.h @ONLY)

configure_file(src/glfw3.pc.in src/glfw3.pc @ONLY)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add subdirectories
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
add_subdirectory(src)

if (GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES)
    add_subdirectory(examples)
endif()

if (GLFW_BUILD_TESTS)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()

if (DOXYGEN_FOUND AND GLFW_BUILD_DOCS)
    add_subdirectory(docs)
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Install files other than the library
# The library is installed by src/CMakeLists.txt
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if (GLFW_INSTALL)
    install(DIRECTORY include/GLFW DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
            FILES_MATCHING PATTERN glfw3.h PATTERN glfw3native.h)

    install(FILES "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3Config.cmake"
                  "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake"
            DESTINATION "${GLFW_CONFIG_PATH}")

    install(EXPORT glfwTargets FILE glfw3Targets.cmake
            EXPORT_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES
            DESTINATION "${GLFW_CONFIG_PATH}")
    install(FILES "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/src/glfw3.pc"
            DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/pkgconfig")

    # Only generate this target if no higher-level project already has
    if (NOT TARGET uninstall)
        configure_file(cmake_uninstall.cmake.in
                       cmake_uninstall.cmake IMMEDIATE @ONLY)

        add_custom_target(uninstall
                          "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P
                          "${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake")
        set_target_properties(uninstall PROPERTIES FOLDER "GLFW3")
    endif()
endif()
```

Comment: Can you use your compiler from the commandline to build a HelloWorld? If you try you might discover the problems which cmake encounters when trying the same.

Comment: yes, i can use command line to build helloworld fine.

Comment: i got it to work. i had to put the folder cmake is in into system path and execute cmake in the glfw folder where the CMakeList.txt is located. during compilation it says it can't find doxygen and performing test _GLFW_HAS_64ASLR Failed. are those important?

Comment: Can we see your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add your updated CMake build log to your question, and modify your question post to include details of the different issue.

Comment: CMakeList.txt added in the question post. can't find the updated CMake build log.